# Page being cut in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Thanks in advance for helping me with this problem, it's driving me up the wall.

I have a site that renders fine with firefox, chrome, safari but on IE the vertical scroll bar is not functional.

I'm using sticky footer css to make sure the footer is pushed to the bottom and it works fine in the other browsers but I suspect it's affecting the height in IE

any help is appreciated.

The site is up at dev.rakozi.com

thank you.

Comment: The way the page is made I don't get a vertical scroll bar at all in any browser. I do however get a JS error.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly in Chrome you don't get scroll bars at all, no matter how high the window is (because the footer is set to fixed).

In ie 7 you get scroll bars that appear but scroll to nothing. In ie8 the footer doesn't stay fixed properly, but you don't get scrollable scroll bars (and for some reason the background gets corrupted on my computer if I adjust the height too much).

Can you clarify your question a bit more, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Removing height:100% from the body in ie7 makes the scroll bars go away, if that helps?